# Pass route param from parent to child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routes structured like so:

```
parent/:id
    |
    child
    |
    child
```

Can I obtain the param from the parent component via:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
  });
}
```

and then just attach it as an input on the `<router-output>` somehow? Or do I have to pull the value from each child the same way I did the parent?

What is the **best** way to pass the `id` param from the parent component to all child components?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, the point is how to pass parameters deep in a component tree. In this case have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: That is essentially the question, yeah. What would a service look like for this example? How would I obtain the param from the service to be able to  inject into the children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to access parent route parameters and there is no plans to change it [#12767](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12767#issuecomment-260493205), so the only way is workaround using service or localStorage, whatever you like.

```
   class Service {
        public params:Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

        public next(params):void { this.params.next(params); }
   }

   class Parent {
        constructor(service:Service, route:ActivatedRoute){
             activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => service.next(params));
        }
   }

   class Child {
        constructor(service:Service){
             service.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
        }
   }
```

Here are some ways that components can intercommunicate:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: What would a service look like in this case? What would be the best way to get the `id` param into the service to be able to inject into the child components?

Comment: Added simplified example.

Comment: your usage of 'next' and 'params' was confusing but this generally seems like the way to do it, for now at least. There still seems to be an open ticket on this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13058. Would you mind elaborating on the snippet a little so I can accept?

Comment: Do you have specific question? The idea is to create service with additional `Subject` and use it to redirect necessary events to child components. Personally i don't like this solution since it is not reusable. Generic solution would automatically merge all active route parameters and provide up-to-date snapshot of parameters, but this will take time to implement properly.

Comment: This answered the question in terms of the approach and how the Angular team wants it to be done. I tried to implement this but the child component is unable to subscribe to events emitted from parent > service > child. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280325/passing-parent-route-params-to-child-via-service

Comment: What about this.route.parent?

Comment: Didn't work for me. I suspect the parent constructor is executed before the child? If I use BehaviorSubject it works. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: bgraham's answer below exactly solves this problem (since Angulr 5.2) and should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 11):

With Angular router 5 (who knows about 2?), you wouldn't be far ; there is a parent object which is also an ActivatedRoute.

In the child route, you can get it like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.parentRouteId = +params["id"];
    console.log(this.parentRouteId);
  });
}
```

And your route must be defined something like that:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/my-page' },
      { path: 'my-page', redirectTo: component: MyChildComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: This answer should get way more upvotes as there are several similar questions which are answered by this. The relevant documentation for the parent property on the the ActivatedRoute can be found at https://angular.io/guide/router#router-state and https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent

Comment: Your answer was actually option B of my question: "Or do I have to pull the value from each child the same way I did the parent?". I suppose that when I asked this I was hoping there would be a way to achieve method A without having to have the child take in all of the route info.

Comment: @JamieKudla, I know what you mean. The fist way would be classy but it doesn't work this way. So the second is the best way not to have extensive mess and complications in your code.

Comment: My children-routes contain loadChilren and when I check the parent it is null

Answer (score 6):

There's another answer to this problem since angular 5.2

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})
```

You can pass in a setting into your root RouterModule to tell it to always inherit from its parents. imho, this should be the default, but it isn't. This will allow all parameters to be inherited from the all ancestors.