# Passing parent route params to child via service

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to pass route parameters from a parent component to child component using the method that the Angular team currently recommends: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

The parent is able to successfully subscribe to the service which does emit correctly. However, the child does not receive anything when the page is loaded.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AbcService {
  public paramSource: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public getParams(params) {
    this.paramSource.next(params);
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AbcService } from './abc.service';

@Component({
  providers: [AbcService],
  ...,
})

export class AbcComponent {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private abcService: AbcService,
  ) {
    route.params.subscribe(
      (params) => abcService.getParams(params);
    );
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
export class AbcChildComponent {
  constructor(private abcService: AbcService) {
      abcService.paramSource.subscribe((params) => {
          console.log(params);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think code is correct, but event was lost. At the time you call next, nobody is listening to subject. One way is to use `ReplaySubject` another is to call next in `ngAfterViewInit` callback.

Comment: Awesome! My findings were that `ReplaySubject` worked and `ngAfterViewCheck` worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because instance of `AbcService` are **not the same** in parent and child component.

Please declare your `AbcService` in `parent module`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChildComponent,
    ParentComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AbcService
  ]
})
export default class ParentModule { }
```

You don't need to declare at parent component anymore.

#### Parent

```
@Component({
  providers: [AbcService], // <-- Remove this
  ...,
})
```

One more points, I think we should put subscription in `ngOnInit()` instead of constructor.

> The constructor is for simple initializations like wiring constructor parameters to properties. It's not for heavy lifting. We should be able to create a component in a test and not worry that it might do real work — like calling a server! — before we tell it to do so.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#!#the-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook

---

My source structure

```
|- parent.module.ts
|- parent.component.ts
|- parent.routing.ts
|- shared.service.ts
\--- child
       |- child.component.ts
```

#### parent.html

```
<p>Some shared information</p>
<!-- Use router to load child component -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

> Why example work?

I guess because of don't use router to initialize child component.

In my case, the child component only initialize when route to.

P/s: if you find anything is not correct, please correct me.

Comment: I'm confused as to why it works in the angular example then... Where would you put the parentModule? Also, why is it better to put it inside of `ngOnInit()` instead of the contstructor? Angular docs use constructor for their example.

Comment: Hmm, I think I will update answer with your question.