# Getting a Route parameter in an Angular child component

Tags: angular

I'm unable to get a routing parameter from a child component in my Angular 6 application

I have the following routes set up in app-routing.module:

```
{
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'inbox',  pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'inbox', loadChildren: './feature/inbox/inbox.module#InboxModule' }
    ]
},
```

And then this in my inbox-routing-module.ts:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: InboxComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'messages',  pathMatch: 'full' },
        {
            path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent
        },
    ]
}
```

This allows me to have a url that looks like this to get to my messages component:

```
item/5200/inbox/messages
```

My problem is that in my ItemLayoutComponent I can get the value of the id field (in this case 5200) with the following code:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

However I need the value of this ID in my MessagesComponent.  Currently the same code gives me null.

Comment: That's a child route, so did you check if it's available via the [`parent`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent)?

Comment: Good point - this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('id') is null unfortunately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass route param from parent to child routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257273/pass-route-param-from-parent-to-child-routes)

Comment: try `route.parent.snapshot.params['id']`

Comment: Comes back as undefined @Yousefkhan

Comment: `this.route.parent` is undefined? @Robbie

Comment: this.route.parent is fine, this.route.parent.snapshot is what gives me the undefined

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out I needed the following:

```
this.route.parent.parent.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

HTML :

```
{
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'inbox',  pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'inbox', loadChildren: './feature/inbox/inbox.module#InboxModule' }
    ]
},
```

TS:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

id: any;

constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
    }

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
            this.id = param.get('id');
        });
```

Comment: Which TS file is this?

Comment: item component file lets say 'ItemLayoutComponent'

Comment: So in the ItemLayoutComponent I can use the code to get the id ok as per my question - problem is that I need it in the MessagesComponent

Comment: than try {
            path: 'messages/:id', component: MessagesComponent
        },

Comment: That's not how I'd like my URL's though (for integration with a legacy app).  I'm trying to get them in the format item/5200/inbox/messages

Answer (score 1):

Problem I faced was, route param in root module path is not exist in feature module's activate snapshot.

From @jonrsharpe, I used to run while loop in bottom-up approach until route param found in parents.

```
var cgName: string = "";
cgName = next.paramMap.get('cgname');
var snap = next;

while (cgName === null && snap.parent !== null) {
     cgName = snap.parent.paramMap.get('cgname');
     snap = snap.parent;
}
```

My route definition was like,

**Root Module**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent },
  {
    path: ':cgname',
    canActivate: [PathGuard],
    component: LoggedUserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'shop', loadChildren: () => import('./../ShoppingModule/shopping.module').then(mod => mod.ShoppingModule) },
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: '', component: LoginRedirectProxyComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' }
    ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

**Feature Module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product', component: ProductDetailComponent, canActivate: [PathGuard] },
  { path: '', component: ShopPageComponent, canActivate: [PathGuard] },
];
```